# Firefox download manager (add-on) integrating with built-in download manager with throttling feature

Tags: firefox, download-manager

The built-in download manager of Firefox 35 has a long list of missing features including such a basic like download and upload data rate throttling. There are a lot of download managers available as complementary add-ons which don't interact with the built-in download manager (They can't be used when a download link is clicked on and/or need to be started explicitly when previous downloads ought to be resumed - when the downloads allow it). Further problems include duplicate configuration and traffic loss (when a download is started in one manager and requires features which are only available in the other and needs to be restarted).

I am looking for a solution which is not based on a concept which immanently wastes my time (as described above), i.e. a download manager which integrates with the build-in manager or disables it efficiently (including settings synchronization). I checked:

- Download Manager Tweak 1.0.8: doesn't integrate with the built-in download manager, at least not with All-in-one Sidebar 0.7.25 installed; throttle features not checked
- Modern Download Manager 0.2.1: integrates well with the built-in download manager and All-in-one Sidebar 0.7.25, but doesn't have any visible or accessible features

and gave up because it became a trial and error search.

A solution in form of an extension would be nice, but is not a requirement (I just can't imagine another solution).

Comment: Why does the download manager need to integrate with the built-in option? Why not use a completely separate manager, like DownThemAll!, for your downloads? If you provide a little more detail about your use case, it should be easier to brainstorm possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

[FlashGot](https://flashgot.net/) and [pyload](http://pyload.org/de:start) do the job. `FlashGot` allows selection of the backend which is used as download manager (supports a large set of download managers) and `pyload` has any imaginable feature - in case one is missing one can still figure out adding other download manager backends.

The fact that a download cannot be resumed with a download manager after being started with another is inevitable.